# AngularJS highlight search no result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter, highlight

I'm using the AngularJS highlight search from
https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/highlight-search-result-angular-filter/

The problem is, that if I search for a keyword the highlight effect works perfect. But as soon as I type a keyword that doesn't exist in the content, it hides all the content. See pictures below:

Highlighted Keyword:
[image: Highlighted Keyword]

Incorrect keyword - no content shown:
[image: iincorrect keyword - no content shown]

Here my JS

```
var newsApp = angular.module("NewsApp",[]);
newsApp.controller("newsCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.posts = [

    {
    "id"        : "1",
    "title"     : "CMS Newsletter - 2018-01-02",
    "content"   : ""TEST CONTENT - ORIGINAL CONTENT IS CONFIDENTIAL",
    },

];
});

newsApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { 
return function(val) { 
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
}; 
}); 

newsApp.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
 return function(text, phrase) {
   if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
     '<span style="background: red;">$1</span>')

 return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
 }
```

Here my HTML

```
     <div class="newsletter-control-bar-left">
                <input type="text" ng-model="search.text" placeholder="Search for Keywords" />
 </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="newsletter-archive">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-3 newsletter-side">
                <li ng-repeat="post in posts"><a href="#{{post.id}}" data-toggle="tab">{{post.title}}</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content col-md-9">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="#">Navigate through the the Newsletter Archive!</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{post.id}}" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search.text">

                <div>
                    <p id="search_para" ng-bind-html="post.content | highlight:search.text">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Somebody knows how to implement maybe a else argument if the keyword is not found, that it highlights nothing instead of hiding the whole content?

Answer (score 0):

You can put you second div into an `ng-if` and say, for example, `ng-if=" $ctrl.search.text.found() === false"`.
You will need to create a function in your controller as:

`let found = () => search.text.match('input.ref', 'words[].ref') ? true : false`

So this will render other content instead to hide everything.

It's too generic but hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey, can you give me an example in my script and HTML. Sorry im very new to angular!